# Would this be considered a dangler?

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence end with a dangler?

"He managed to remain happy about his work **despite being involved in a very dull industry.**"

Comment: tabdulla, welcome to ELU. All new users should have read about [How to Ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking their first question.

Comment: Why do you think so? How do you understand a 'dangler'? Have you *tried* to find an answer elsewhere? If so, what did you find? Unless you provide these details and the context, the question may get closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the participle *involved* in your sentence does not ambiguously refer to either *he* or *his work*, and it doesn't, because someone's work cannot "be involved in a very dull industry;" what can is *work* in a more generic sense. The following sentence would probably have a dangling participle:

> He managed to remain happy about there being a lot of work, despite being involved in a very dull industry.

Here the *involved* ambiguously refers, I think, to both *he* and *a lot of work* (a dull industry *can* involve a lot of work).

However, your sentence does *sound* like it has a dangling participle. It requires the readers to amp up their synapses in order to distinguish *somebody's work* from just *work*. So, if it's your sentence, you should rephrase it.

Comment: Thank you, @Talia. As an aside: is there a reason you placed a comma in front of despite when you modified my original sentence? I know it's not related to the original question, but it has piqued my curiosity.

Comment: Yes, there is. The _despite_ here marks the beginning of a non-restrictive dependent clause, and those need to be separated by a comma. If you remove a non-restrictive clause, what remains can stand alone as a sentence. This doesn't mean non-restrictive clauses contain irrelevant information; they add to the meaning of the sentence, but are not essential for its grammatical sense.

Comment: Nonsense. Commas are used where the intonation demands them; there are no grammatical rules for them in English. And there is no such thing as a "non-restrictive dependent clause". There are non-restrictive **relative** clauses, which are dependent clauses; but this is not one of them. This is an adverbial clause, introduced by the subordinate conjunction (or preposition, if you prefer) _despite_, and it is not either "restrictive" or "non-restrictive".

Comment: @John: Quite. [*I love you despite everything, and it's obvious that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+love+you+despite+everything%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I+love+you+despite+everything%2C+and+it's+obvious+that%22&tbm=bks) I only **need** one comma in this sentence*.

Comment: @John But would you say that a comma is required in this instance?

Comment: A comma can only represent an [oral intonation dip](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html#curve). When you say it out loud, do you hear such a dip? If so, comma; if not, no comma. I can't hear you say it, so I don't know whether a comma is required.

Answer (score 0):

"Despite" is a preposition, thus, the whole phrase "despite being involved in a very dull industry" is a prepositional phrase. We know that prepositional phrases can work as an adjective, therefore, a modifier. Now, does this phrase qualify as a dangling modifier?

A modifier is said to be dangling if it doesn't syntactically relate to the noun it supposed to modify. In this case, we look at the noun the prepositional phrase modifies. By inspection, it seems that the prepositional phrase relates to "He" and not to "work". Therefore, a better sentence construction should be.

> He, despite being involved in a very dull industry, managed to remain happy about his work.

or

> Despite being involved in a very dull industry, he managed to remain happy about his work.